# Simple imap client

Tags: email, courier-imap

I'm writing a very simple IMAP client in Python using imaplib. 
For the front-end, I'm wondering whether it should always connect to the imap store as the courier(imap) service user, or should it connect as the username that belongs to one of the (virtual) imap accounts and authenticate using sasl?

Answer (score 3):

Where possible, use a special-use utility account for these kinds of applications. So, go with the virtual imap accounts via sasl.